# Local Truncation Error of the Midpoint Method.

Tags: taylor-expansion, truncation-error

I'm looking at a past paper and have been asked to show that the Midpoint method:
$$w_{i+1}=w_{i-1}+2hf(t_{i},w_{i})$$ has a local second order truncation error.

with the expansions:
$$W_{i+1}= y + hy' + \frac{h^{2}y''}{2} + O(h^{3})$$ 
$$W_{i-1}= y - hy' + \frac{h^{2}y''}{2} + O(h^{3})$$
$$f(t_{i},w_{i}) = y'$$

So to find the truncation error i rearrange to the following:
$$\frac{w_{i+1}-w_{i-1}}{h}-2hf(t_{i},w_{i})$$

Then by substituting in my taylor expansions i get:
$$2y'+ O(h^{2})-2hy'$$

I think i've made an error but i'm not sure where as this says its first not second order, i think the factors should cancel to leave just $O(h^{2})$ but i cannot find my mistake.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Just after 'so to fine the truncation error I rearrange to the following', you divide by $h$ but left the $h$ attached to the $f(t_{i}, w_{i})$ term. You need to fix up your post by the way, the notation is quite sloppy. It is rather confusing having $y$ and a function $w_{i}$ equal to each other.

Comment: thanks for your reply, ill work on the notation. So just to make sure i know for the future you also divide the function $f(t_{i},w_{i})$ by h aswell?